# How can I show LaTeX commands (without them being parsed)?

Tags: macros

I am including LaTeX in my acknowledgements section of my thesis.

I want to do something like:

```
\item LaTeX - because I can type \text{\cite{latext}} to make a citation\cite{latex}
```

But both instances of `\cite{latex}` are converted.

- How can I make the first `\cite{latex}` display as exactly that in the resulting pdf?

Searching this has been impossibly hard because "cite LaTeX" types of searches return thousands of bibtex, etc....

Comment: For more complicated things you should have a look at [the `showexpl` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/showexpl) which can display both the code and the output.

Comment: @PeterGrill: Am I the only one who thinks it's quite ironic that the showexpl package's readme doesn't have any examples that show the result of using the package...?

Comment: @TomasLycken Follow the link on ctan and have a look into the directory doc ;-)